# Using org.eclipse.core.expressions: expressionLanguage.exsd could not be found

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am following [this guide](http://codeandme.blogspot.de/2013/04/re-using-core-expressions-for-own.html) to incorporate an activation expression (from core expressions) into my own extension point. As the guide says, I have created my extension point schema as follows:

[image: screenshot]

But as you can see, I get errors for the referenced elements. (**Element 'xxx' is not defined**).
Actually, when I switch to the definition tab and double-click in the schema URL in the **Schema inclusions** list, I get the error message **schema:/org.eclipse.core.expressions/schema/expressionLanguage.exsd** could not be found.

My first suspicion was that something might have changed here for Eclispe Kepler, but the docs say anything about it. And I imported the *org.eclipse.core.expressions* plug-in from the *Plug-Ins* view into my workspace temporarily and checked if the referenced schema is actually where it is supposed to be (which it is). So this seems to be ok.

My next suspicion was that this had something to do with my target platform, so I double-checked my target platform, but I don't see any issue here. It includes (among others) the features

- **org.eclipse.platform** 4.3.2.v20140221-1852
- **org.eclipse.platform.source** 4.3.2.v20140221-1852
- **org.eclipse.rcp** 4.3.2.v20140221-1700
- **org.eclipse.rcp.source** 4.3.2.v20140221-1700

and the Core Expressions bundles are there as well:

- **org.eclipse.core.expressions** 3.4.501.v20131118-1915
- **org.eclipse.core.expressions.source** 3.4.501.v20131118-1915

I am currently stuck. Any pointer what else I can check or how I can fix this is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it is in the source plugin so try 'org.eclipse.core.expressions.source' in the schema

Comment: Interesting idea. Actually, I got rid of the error just before reading your comment, but I have tried anyways. Obviously both `schema://org.eclipse.core.expressions/schema/expressionLanguage.exsd` and `schema://org.eclipse.core.expressions.source/schema/expressionLanguage.exsd` seem to work (if the environment works ...).

Answer (score 1):

Does your plug-in file (org.eclipse.core.expression.xxx.jar) actually have the schema file?

Today I had same problem and found that the jar file doesn't have the schema file.
I downloaded source jar file which have the schema file (Actually I found the source jar file from : http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.2/org.eclipse.core/expressions/3.4.400) and put the schema file into my jar file and it solves the problem.

Good luck.

Comment: I guess the main problem is/was that the schema is located in the source bundle. So, including the source bundle in the target platform will make the error go away. (I don't think it's a good idea to add the schema to the downloaded bundle file, because this violates packaging - version identifier with maven, e.g.).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, several chaotic attempts of

- reloading the target platform
- cleaning all projects
- restarting Eclipse with `-clean` switch

seems to have done the trick. I am not sure what caused this, but now the error has vanished (and I hope it stays this way).